# Section index in tableview without section (Swift)

Tags: swift

Question 1: How can i have section index in tableview without section?

Question 2: Could i have those section index for specific rows in a table? For example: i want the section index to be implemented whenever indexpath.row > 4.

Answer (score 1):

- Table views in `UIKit` always have sections and rows. By saying you don't want a section, you are really saying that you simply want only one section (at section index 0) that holds all rows (with indexes relative to section index 0).
  Note: You can easily have a section without a section header in which case the user will never know that all rows are actually contained in a section.
- When you implement your table view data source, you will want to implement `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` in order to let the table view know how many sections and rows you want.

See [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean with only one single section (you can't have no sections).  Here's how I do this:

- Create index titles that are just string versions of the array indexes.  If there are too many to fit on the screen, iOS will skip some and replace them with bullets to make it clear that there are some indexes not being displayed.  You will be guaranteed that the index range is the same as your row range.  (Unless you have zero rows).
- Instead of returning the section index, return -1.  This will do nothing.  Programatically scroll to the ROW of the passed in index.

```
    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        if myDataSourceArray.count > 0 {
            return Array(1...myDataSourceArray.count).map({String($0)}).map({ String($0) })
        }

        return []
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), at: .middle, animated: true)
        return -1
    }
```

(I actually set my minimum count to 20, rather than zero, as there's not much point in having an index when all items in the table are on the screen.  But you do need to check for at least greater than zero, otherwise it will try to create an index of "1" for a table with no rows, and this will cause a crash.)

You may want different index titles other than just numbers, but hopefully this gives you some idea on how it can be done.  Once you have a different number of indexes to what you have rows, you would have to come up with some other more complicated way of relating index numbers or index titles to row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Question1:To have section index in tableview without section, you can make height of section to 0.

Question2: If indexPath.row>4, get section index as: yourArray[indexPath.section]